# How to use Flask with types hints in python

Tags: python, flask, type-hinting

This basic Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return '<h1>Hello world</h1>'
```

It makes `pylance` throw errors in `@app.route('/')` saying that:

```
Type of "route" is partially unknown
  Type of "route" is "(rule: str, **options: Any) -> (*args: Unknown, **kwargs: Unknown) -> Unknown"
```

And

```
Untyped function decorator obscures type of function; ignoring decorator
```

How can I solve this error and, in a more general matter, work with flask and type hints without any problem?

Comment: Sounds like you need type stubs for Flask.  https://pypi.org/project/flask-hintful/ maybe?